# tempermonkey,setTimeout is not run when open mutiple window throgh win.open

Tags: javascript, settimeout

PageA(  ScriptA), window.open(PageB, ScriptB).

It's a button in PageB, click it when window loaded.

In PageA, will open more then 10 PageBs.

The scriptB in PageB it's not run until I set the PageB actived and refresh it。

so， settimeout's problem? or tempermonkey 's problem?

```
 (function() {
   'use strict';
    
      if(location.href.indexOf('autorestart') > 0 ){
          setTimeout(()=>{
             var button = $("button.ant-btn-primary span")[0];
          console.info(button);
         $(button).click();
      }, 5000);
  }
})();
```

Comment: What you mean by "tempermonkey"? its a service that you use or something like that?

Comment: If a get right (its a little unclear), it could be the way you are loading the scripts, so in advance I can tell that use setTimeout to control the flow of code is a bad idea, but please share a more complete code, including script A and B so we can help you

Comment: @KleberGermano tampermonkey is a very popular browser extension that allows you to write your own code on any website.

Comment: It's impossible to understand the question for me